# Converting json data to an HTML table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have an array of data in php and I need to display this data in a HTML table.  Here is what an example data set looks like.

```
Array(
  Array
  (
     [comparisonFeatureId] => 1182
     [comparisonFeatureType] => Category
     [comparisonValues] => Array
                 (
                 [0] => Not Available
                 [1] => Standard
                 [2] => Not Available
                 [3] => Not Available
                 )
    [featureDescription] => Rear Seat Heat Ducts
),)
```

The dataset is a comparison of 3 items (shown in the comparisonValues index of the array)

In the end I need the row to look similar to this

```
<tr class="alt2 section_1"> 
   <td><strong>$record['featureDescription']</strong></td> 
   <td>$record['comparisonValues'][0]</td> 
   <td>$record['comparisonValues'][1]</td> 
   <td>$record['comparisonValues'][2]</td> 
   <td>$record['comparisonValues'][3]</td> 
</tr>
```

The problem I am coming across is how to best do this.  Should I create the entire table HTML on the server side pass it over an ajax call and just dump pre-rendered HTML data into a div or pass the json data and render the table client side.

Any elegant suggestions?

Comment: I would build the table in the ajax script and then load it. It's the easiest way. Then you can just inject a fully formed table into the div or whatever.

Answer (score 4):

That depends. There are several factors to be taken into account:

1. How much CPU and network bandwidth do you want to waste on the webserver? Generating and sending HTML eats more than just sending a compact JSON string.
2. How much CPU and memory do you want to waste on the webbrowser? Generating a table in HTML DOM tree eats more than just inserting a ready-generated string as `innerHTML`.
3. How reuseable do you want the webservice to be? Returning "static" HTML isn't useful for everyone. A more flexible format like XML or JSON is more useful (also for yourself in the future).

As far, I'd suggest returning JSON and have JS/jQuery to populate it on the client side.

---

**Update:** assuming that the JSON data will arrive in this format

```
var json = {"features": [{
    "comparisonFeatureId": 1182,
    "comparisonFeatureType": "Category",
    "comparisonValues": [ "Not Available", "Standard", "Not Available", "Not Available" ],
    "featureDescription": "Rear Seat Heat Ducts"
}, {
    "comparisonFeatureId": 1183,
    "comparisonFeatureType": "Category",
    "comparisonValues": [ "Not Available", "Standard", "Not Available", "Not Available" ],
    "featureDescription": "Some Description"
}]};
```

and that you have an empty table like this

```
<table id="table"></table>
```

then you can use the following jQuery script to fill it the way you described in the question

```
$.each(json.features, function(i, feature) {
    var row = $('<tr class="alt2 section_1">').appendTo($('#table'));
    row.append($('<td>').append($('<strong>').text(feature.featureDescription)));
    $.each(feature.comparisonValues, function(j, comparisonValue) {
        row.append($('<td>').text(comparisonValue));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

dnaluz,

as mentioned by others, there are great libs out there to do thios client side. I'd also take the stance that you'd be best sending the json array to the client and then using the lib to present the data in tabular format.

Altho i mention the use of nice presentation libs to create the table, below is a little function that i use for lightweight quick and dirty table visualizations from a json array:

```
function CreateTableFromJson(objArray) {
    // has passed in array has already been deserialized
    var array = typeof  objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;

    str = '<table class="tableNormal">';
    str += '<tr>';
    for (var index in array[0]) {
        str += '<th scope="col">' + index + '</th>';
    }
    str += '</tr>';
    str += '<tbody>';
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        str += (i % 2 == 0) ? '<tr class="alt">' : '<tr>';
        for (var index in array[i]) {
            str += '<td>' + array[i][index] + '</td>';
        }
        str += '</tr>';
    }
    str += '</tbody>'
    str += '</table>';
    return str;
}
```

hope this is useful in some minor way..
jim

**[edit]** - here's a link to a page using a very similar technique:
http://www.zachhunter.com/2010/04/json-objects-to-html-table/

Answer (score 1):

Nice thing about sending as JSON is you remove the presentation layer from the data layer. I'd do the table client side - there are libraries and blog tutorials to handle rendering.

If you have the funds, extJS is a rather easy way to get that going too.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

I think either way is OK... I have found it easier to include plenty of markup in the response from the server side, when you're displaying a whole table (or row) at a time.  If you're dynamically poking bits of data into a table that's already on the page, you might want to render it on the client side.