# create a table using json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

If I have the some data being returned from my ajax call.  I need to loop through and create an Html string that creates a table like:

```
 ID    NAME                  Object Type
 ==============================================
 1     SWT-F1-S32-RTR-1      Network Switch
 2     SWT-44-SR1-RTR-1      Network Switch
 etc.
```

Here's what my json data looks like:

```
[
   {
      "name": "SWT-F1-S32-RTR-1",
      "id": "1",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-44-SR1-RTR-1",
      "id": "2",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-44-SR1-SW-1",
      "id": "3",
      "dict_value": "Network chassis"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-F1-S32-SW-2",
      "id": "4",
      "dict_value": "Network chassis"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-44-165-SW-1",
      "id": "5",
      "dict_value": "Network chassis"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-44-263-SW-1",
      "id": "6",
      "dict_value": "Network chassis"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-11-228-SW-1",
      "id": "7",
      "dict_value": "Network chassis"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-F1-S32-SW-1",
      "id": "8",
      "dict_value": "Network chassis"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-F2-204-SW-1",
      "id": "9",
      "dict_value": "Network chassis"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-R1-CC104-SW-1",
      "id": "10",
      "dict_value": "Network chassis"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-5-103-SW-1",
      "id": "11",
      "dict_value": "Network chassis"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-F1-1PF-SW-1",
      "id": "12",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-F1-1PE-SW-1",
      "id": "13",
      "dict_value": "Network chassis"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-11-123-SW-1",
      "id": "15",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-32-M402-SW-1",
      "id": "17",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-66-102-SW-1",
      "id": "18",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-R1-CC011-SW-1",
      "id": "19",
      "dict_value": "Network chassis"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-R1-CC239-SW-1",
      "id": "20",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-R1-CCPH-SW-1",
      "id": "21",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-32-K218-SW-1",
      "id": "23",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-SB1-204-SW-1",
      "id": "24",
      "dict_value": "Network chassis"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-SB3-107-SW-1",
      "id": "25",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-SB4-110-SW-1",
      "id": "26",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-5-119-SW-1",
      "id": "27",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-F2-113-SW-1",
      "id": "39",
      "dict_value": "Network chassis"
   },
   {
      "name": "Core Switch HSRP",
      "id": "91",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-MLO-106-SW-1",
      "id": "275",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-STP-001-SW-1",
      "id": "277",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-F1-169-SW-1",
      "id": "281",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-R1-F108-SW-1",
      "id": "283",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-GH-001-SW-1",
      "id": "285",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-11-228-SW-2",
      "id": "301",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-44-010-SW-1",
      "id": "303",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-44-141-SW-1",
      "id": "305",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-F1-169-SW-2",
      "id": "309",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-F2-114-SW-1",
      "id": "311",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-66-114-SW-1",
      "id": "313",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-R1-1109-SW-1",
      "id": "315",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-32-L009-SW-1",
      "id": "317",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-SB1-204-SW-2",
      "id": "319",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-5-103-SW-2",
      "id": "321",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-5-114-SW-1",
      "id": "323",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-F1-1PL-SW-1",
      "id": "325",
      "dict_value": "Network chassis"
   },
   {
      "name": "CAES-0xx-CAGE",
      "id": "365",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-R1-H109-SW-1",
      "id": "379",
      "dict_value": "Network chassis"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-FM-001-SW-1",
      "id": "385",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-LSQ-BSMT-SW-1",
      "id": "415",
      "dict_value": "Network switch"
   },
   {
      "name": "SWT-44-152-SW-1",
      "id": "417",
      "dict_value": "Network chassis"
   }
]
```

**EDIT 1**
Here's the code I have so far:

```
    $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo site_url('switches/getallswitches/');?>",
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(returnDataFromController) {
                    var htmlstring;
                    htmlstring="<select name='L2Locations' id='L2Locations'>";
                    htmlstring = htmlstring + "<option value='all'>All</option>";

                    //console.log(returnDataFromController);
                     var JSONdata=returnDataFromController;
                     console.log(JSONdata);
                     if (JSONdata.length != 0) 
                     {
                            $.each(JSONdata, function(i, objswitch) {
                            var row = $('<tr class="alt2 section_1">').appendTo($('#table'));
                            row.append($('<td>').append($('<strong>').text(objswitch.name)));
                            $.each(objswitch.id, function(j, comparisonValue) {
                                row.append($('<td>').text(comparisonValue));
                            });
                        });

                     }

                }//success


        });//end ajax
```

It's based on the example in the other post.  But i'm not sure how to convert "row" into an html string so i can ultimately do something like (#nameofdiv).html(htmlstring).

Sorry to all the guys who have read this post so far.  It's been a crazy day and not that you have to check my other posts before you make nasty remarks, but for what it's worth, i have been working on some interesting ajaax problems with others on stackoverflow today.  And I guess I was just too quick to hit enter. I got nailed immediately!  wow.  Anyways.  Thanks for being patient.  Hopefully, this post is a little clearer.

Comment: What are you having trouble with?  Looping through the data?  Creating a table?

Comment: Guys, sorry. but to answer your questions and put downs, I have read the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016903/converting-json-data-to-an-html-table?rq=1.  I didn't quite understand the answer showing the javascript to create the table.  Specifically, the comments made by BalusC seemed applicable, but i couldn't get it working.

Comment: @dot: What didn't you understand?  Show us what you have so far, and where you are stuck.

Comment: @Rocket - I will update my post in a sec with my code.  Thanks.

Comment: @Rocket, please note the section called  "Edit 1" in my post.  Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to "convert" `row` to an HTML string.  It's a jQuery object, and you can pass those to `html` and `append`.

Comment: I found my bug.  I didn't change the name of table to my table.  I'm sorry.  Thanks for the help Rocket and for being so patient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the table name referenced in the loop was incorrect.